# Unable to debug C++ files in Mac Mojave

Tags: mac, python, debug, c++

I tried to debug using lldb but it shows following errors.

```
sanad@Sanads-MacBook-Pro  ~/Desktop/cppLab  lldb fact    12:24:23
(lldb) target create "fact"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 52, in <module>
    import weakref
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/weakref.py", line 14, in <module>
    from _weakref import (
ImportError: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref
Current executable set to 'fact' (x86_64).
(lldb)
```

I tried to install weakref using pip but I got the following.

```
pip install weakref
Collecting weakref
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement weakref (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for weakref
```

My python version is 2.7.1 and 3.7.2 when I write python3.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to say that I had this error on OSX because my default system Python was 2.7, and I brew installed "python@2" while installing another package.

If you're on OSX and are using homebrew, check your packages installed with brew by running brew list, and if "python@2" appears in that list, and Python 2.7 is your system Python, you can remove the brew installed package with brew remove python@2 --ignore-dependencies